# Multiple fixest_multi models and shape parameter - modelsummary package

Tags: r, dplyr, modelsummary, fixest

Again, thanks to Laurent for answering questions and supporting the `modelsummary`package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)
fit<-mtcars %>% feols(c(mpg,hp )~1)
fit_1 <- mtcars %>% feols(c(mpg,hp,wt )~1)
fit_2 <- mtcars %>% feols(c(mpg,hp,gear, wt )~1)
modelsummary(c(fit, fit_1, fit_2), shape=model + statistic ~ term, output="flextable")
```

We obtain the long column of estimates from all 3 models (which are simple averages) as in:

[image: original]

So is there a way to rearrange the columns and the rows either using internal `modelsummary` functions or external work to the following format:

[image: goal]

The biggest problem is moving the terms around so that they are aligned on the same line (note that the order of terms between fit_1 and fit_2 is changed) and the rest is filled with NA. Would really appreciate any help! It's a part of a larger problem I've been trying to solve unsuccessfully for the last 3 weeks.

Comment: Hi! I need to correct a fact: It's `modelsummary` that supports `fixest` and not the other way around :-) Vincent has been doing a fantastic job in so doing. As regards the question: no idea, sorry! Good luck!

Comment: Hi Laurent! Sorry I've been going between your and Laurent's packages a lot in the last few months and got confused. Thank you both for your contributions to science!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to output to a data frame and reshape manually:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)
library(flextable)
fit<-mtcars %>% feols(c(mpg,hp )~1)
fit_1 <- mtcars %>% feols(c(mpg,hp,wt )~1)
fit_2 <- mtcars %>% feols(c(mpg,hp,gear, wt )~1)
models <- c(fit, fit_1, fit_2)

modelsummary(
    models,
    output = "dataframe",
    shape = model + statistic ~ term) |>
    mutate(
      fit = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 8)),
      model = trimws(model)) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = "fit", values_from = "(Intercept)") |>
    select(-statistic, -part, ` ` = model) |>
    flextable()
```

[image]

This is a *very* customized shape and modeling context, so I can't currently think of a way to achieve that purely using internal `modelsummary` functions arguments.

Comment: This is great! Thank you Vincent! I spent several days on building a different approach but a pivot_wider works great here. I extracted the rep factors from the original fixest_multi models and made `fit = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 8))` driven by the model themselves.